# Динамическая загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: файлы, ajax, php

**Доброго времени суток!**

Прошу прощения за вопрос нубского характера. В общем, как наиболее рационально и удобно можно загружать файлы на сервер динамически, используя лишь AJAX(JQuery) и PHP ?
Хотелось бы по возможности увидеть самые ключевые фрагменты. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

1. Вариант номер раз. Не вижу смысла пересказывать своими словами, поэтому просто даю ссылку на статью [Новые возможности XMLHttpRequest2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120917/). Но перед тем, как радостно потирать ручки, я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на те браузеры, которые поддерживают определенные API.
2. Этот вариант используют на сегодняшний день подавляющее кол-во плагинов. Это ни что иное, как использование скрытого iframe. По сути, работа JS/jQuery части плагина заключается в том, чтоб внедрить этот самый iframe на страницу и сделать на него target формы. Это и руками можно сделать за пять минут.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Прежде чем задать данный вопрос, я, конечно же, погуглил, как следует. Т мне, как помню, встречалось что-то связанное с iframe. Но вот такой вопрос: разве ифреймы еще не устарели? В смысле, они ведь уходят в прошлое, да и на безопасность приложения они разве не влияют?

Comment: Нет, фреймовый подход еще не скоро устареет.

А вообще, самая толковая библиотека загрузки файлов - http://www.uploadify.com/ - использует либо возможности html5, либо (если первое не поддерживает браузер) флэш-загрузчик.